# PostgreSQL - Store JSON Object to Postgresql Table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with type varchar[]

| Field Name | Field Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| data | varchar[][] |
| insert_date | timestamps |

I have a data json object

```
{
 { 
  name : "Mr. A",
  class: 
  {
    class_id: 1,
    exam: 95,
  },
  {
    class_id: 2,
    exam: 78,
  }
 },
 { 
  name : "Mr. B",
  class: 
  {
    class_id: 1,
    exam: 87,
  },
  {
    class_id: 2,
    exam: 87,
  }
 }
}
```

how do i insert the data into 1 row?

Comment: De-normalizing using arrays (`varchar[]`) is pretty much always a bad idea. But it's totally unclear to me what exactly you are trying to store into the table. I can't relate any of the JSON keys to the columns in your table. Why don't you just store the JSON value into a `jsonb` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be use `jsonb` to store JSON data in your table.

```
CREATE TABLE customer {
  contact JSONB
}
```

Example(Object) :-
Insert Object JSON Value

```
Insert into customer(contact )
Values('{ "phones":[ {"type": "mobile", "phone": "001001"} , {"type": "fix", "phone": "002002"} ] }')
```

Example(Array) :-
Insert array JSON Value

```
Insert into customer(contact )
Values('[ {"type": "mobile", "phone": "001001"} , {"type": "fix", "phone": "002002"} ]')
```